# Curl in angular 4

Tags: angular, curl

I need to make an api call for this post request.
this is the CURL URL:  `curl "https://api.lufthansa.com/v1/oauth/token" -X POST -d "client_id=28fu8yg7tx35qkq34e6jg96fy" -d "client_secret=6jc933eePE2" -d "grant_type=client_credentials"`

I have tried something like this in angular 4

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class ExchangeService {
public data : any;
  url: string = 'https://api.lufthansa.com/v1/oauth/token';

    constructor (private http: HttpClient) { }

    sendPostRequest() {
        //  const headers = new HttpHeaders()
        //      .set('cache-control', 'no-cache')
        //      .set('content-type', 'application/json');

         const body = {
            client_id: 'snsmgdjcqa2rtsr6y6fwfkfw',
            client_secret: 't5E5ySzaKw',
            grant_type: 'client_credentials'
         }

         return this.http
                    .post(this.url, body)
                    .subscribe(res => this.data = res);
    } 

}
```

But this is not working.

the error says:

```
OPTIONS https://api.lufthansa.com/v1/oauth/token 596 (596)

localhost/:1 Failed to load https://api.lufthansa.com/v1/oauth/token: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 596.
```

Comment: The client secret in your angular code is different to the one in your curl code, im guessing its just an example

Comment: @Dale i have kept random numbers. but in my code i am entering it correctly.

Comment: Can you put error?

Comment: @JavascriptHuppTechnologies now you can find that in my question

Comment: It's CORS issue.